# XLS with formula in more than one cells within a column with Python

Tags: python, excel, xls

After a long day playing with lots of variants I was left with this code:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import Workbook, Formula
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = open_workbook("test.xls")
wb = copy(rb)

s = wb.get_sheet(0)
s.write(2,4, Formula('D3-B3') )
wb.save('test.xls')
```

This works to edit a XLSfile and allowed me to enter a formula in a cell. Now I'm stuck on how can I edit a column to put a formula in the more than one cell that would continue to each cell in the column with the data from the cells in that row, like I did with D3-B3 the row number would change each cell to match that row.

Answer (score 1):

With a simple loop:

```
s = wb.get_sheet(0)
last_row = 10  # change to your last required row
for i in range(4, last_row + 1): 
    s.write(2, i, Formula('D{row}-B{row}'.format(row=i-1)))
wb.save('test.xls')
```